# Non-blocking DatagramSocket?

Tags: java, android, sockets

I'm currently developing a client application for Android that is supposed to do non-blocking reception of packets through UDP. Is there any way to setup a DatagramSocket so that it is non-blocking on its receive()?

Basically what I'm asking is how to set the MSG_DONTWAIT flag for a DatagramSocket.

Comment: Huh? And how do you suggest I implement the functionality of a non-blocking socket using a blocking one?

Comment: @MarekSebera How exactly do you know what he needs? A futile remark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is `java.nio.channels.DatagramChannel` and friends.

Comment: Seems to be just what I needed! I'll do some tests and provide a more elaborate response as soon as I've got it working :) thanks!